# How to retrieve Square orderIds for Call to BatchRetrieveORders

Tags: square

I want to retrieve a list of orders using the Square API. The call to retrieve orders is a POST call with a String array of order_ids however I'm not sure where I can get this information. In the docs they said I can use the `ListTransactions` endpoint to get this information but I'm not able to find the `order_id` within the response.

The documentation to retrieve `Orders` located at: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-batchretrieveorders

see sample response of `ListTransactions`: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions

> The Orders API does not support listing of orders. To access order
>   details, you will need to fetch the order's ID by querying
>   transactions using the ListTransactions and RetrieveTransaction
>   endpoints, and then fetching the order using the BatchRetrieveOrders
>   endpoint

Reference: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/orders-api-overview

The goal is to get a list of recent transactions/orders that list out exactly what was purchased. The `Transactions` model doesn't contain `Items` whereas the `Orders` model does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Transaction` object will include an `order_id` field if you included it during the `Charge` request. If you did not pass the `order_id` to the `Charge` request, then it will not show up.

Furthermore - just for clarity's sake, if you use Square Point of Sale, or if you haven't included the `order_id` previously but still would like to view itemizations for transactions, please look at V1 `ListPayments` which will include it even if there's no `order_id`.

References:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-transaction
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-payments

Comment: Thanks sjosey. I have a follow up. when I make a call to GET /v1/{location_id}/payments, I get the error Provided merchant_id and merchant_id in authorization do not match up. I checked many times that the accessToken and locationId I am using belong to the same merchant. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? I'm not seeing that error, what is the exact error you receive? Are you using OAuth, or trying to run this against your own account?

Comment: I am using an OAuth account. These are the steps I've taken thus far:
1) I've authorized a merchant using oauth2/authorize
2) I exchange the code for the merchant's accessToken
3) using the merchants accessToken I retrieve a list of locations
4) I get the location_id and now make a call to get payments using this location_id and the same Authorization Bearer accessToken as I used while retrieving the locations.

You can email me at bhavik.patel0190@gmail.com if you would like to look at my account.

Comment: sure can; appreciate the help.