# How to retrieve orders list from Square using Square API V2

Tags: api, square-connect

I'm attempting to get a list of recent transactions/orders from the Square Connect API V2 that lists out exactly what was purchased.

I tried the suggestion posted here:
[How to retrieve Square orderIds for Call to BatchRetrieveORders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786827/how-to-retrieve-square-orderids-for-call-to-batchretrieveorders)

and received the error "Provided merchant_id and merchant_id in authorization do not match up."

I also attempted "v2/locations/(locationID)/orders/batch-retrieve" and received the error:

```
     {
  "success": false,
  "message": {
    "resource_bundle_name": "com.squareup.webservice.WebserviceMessages",
    "key": "there.was.a.problem.processing.this.request",
    "arguments": []
  },
  "debug_info": ""
}
```

I am able to get a list of transactions, but it isn't useful to me without the item information.

I'm using a personal account with the Personal Access Token.

Comment: Are you trying to get the Transactions/Orders that were processed using v2 or are you trying to retrieve these from orders made on a POS?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a well-handled error in terms of its messaging. I suspect that the error message is telling you what you need to know. From [this post](https://www.sellercommunity.com/t5/Developer-Discussions/i-get-this-error-while-list-payment/td-p/16261), a Square employee mentioned that the cause is likely that you are:

> using OAuth credentials for one merchant but attempting to retrieve data for another merchant. For example, if you have OAuth tokens for merchant A with location B but try to list payments for location token X that belongs to a different merchant Y, you will get this error.

You should validate that the token you're using is correct for the merchant you're trying to retrieve data for. If you're certain it's correct, I'd reach out to Square directly as there may be an issue with this token.

Comment: Thank you Jamie. This is for a personal account, so I am using a Personal Access Token (I updated my question to clarify this). I have confirmed the token is valid. I may have to reach out to Square.